# PHP - File Upload spitting out error

Tags: php, file, file-upload, upload

I was working on a simple file upload exercise i've gotten from my WebDev Class - We actually only had to copy the code and integrate it to fit our needs.
I tried to do so for my project, sadly it will keep on echoing out the same error.

```
<?php

$allowed_filetypes = array('.jpg','.gif','.bmp','.png', '.jpeg'); 
$max_filesize = 524288; 
$upload_path = 'uploads/'; 

$filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name']; 
$ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1); 
var_export($_FILES, $ext);

 if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes))
  die('The file you attempted to upload is not allowed.');


 if(filesize($_FILES['usrfile']['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize)
  die('The file you attempted to upload is too large.');


 if(!is_writable($upload_path))
  die('You cannot upload to the specified directory, please CHMOD it to 777.');


 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['usrfile']['tmp_name'],$upload_path . $filename))
     echo 'Your file upload was successful, view the file <a href="' . $upload_path .  $filename . '" title="Your File">here</a>';
  else
     echo 'There was an error during the file upload.  Please try again.';

?>
```

It keeps on giving me the 'wrong filetype' error, with all of defined types in the array.

```
<form id='upload' action="uploadfile.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td >Choose a File to Upload</td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td >Select File</td>
            <td  ><input type="file"  name="userfile"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=2 id="sub"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" ></td>
        </tr>
    </Table>
</form>
```

Comment: Do an echo of what the file type is first.

Answer (score 0):

The `'tmp_name'` index contains a *temporary* file name, not the one the file really had. That's stored in `'name'`. See [this page](http://us.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) for information.

Additionally, you should:

1. check for errors in the `'error'` index.
2. use [`pathinfo`](http://us.php.net/pathinfo) to get the extension,
3. lowercase it before searching the array,
4. add some randomness to the uploaded file name to avoid overwriting existing files.

Comment: Sadly, changing it to the 'name' doesn't help, still giving me out the error that the file is not allowed ==> See echo in first if

Comment: Then you should `var_export($_FILES, $ext);` right before the first if and post that in your question (as well as the updated code you're using now).

Comment: @Quantaqa: `var_export` is a debugging tool, not a magical fix - my idea was to see what values it prints for you. Can you please post what it outputs to the page?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was not familiar with the var_export() ==> Output:       array ( )The file you attempted to upload is not allowed.

Comment: If it produces an empty array, that means your `$_FILES` is empty. What does the HTML form you're submitting look like - does it have an `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute?

Comment: Yes, it should be set in my tags - I added the htmlform to the initial post.

Comment: That's odd, everything I can think of (except some quite unlikely scenarios) seems to be in order. Does replacing `var_export` with `var_dump` show any more information? Which version of php are you running (on which OS)? Does your php.ini modify any [settings related to file uploads](http://us.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sect.file-uploads), do all those settings look correct to you? `$_FILES` being empty is unusual and suggests you're not submitting the form - is your `<form>` HTML in the same php file as it's submitting to?

Answer (score 0):

$filename = $_FILES['usrfile']['**name**'];

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as firstly you have to always echo the $_FILES array then start debuging.
change this line from

```
$allowed_filetypes = array('.jpg','.gif','.bmp','.png', '.jpeg');
```

to

```
$allowed_filetypes = array('jpg','gif','bmp','png', 'jpeg');
```

change the follwing line

```
if(filesize($_FILES['usrfile']['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize)
```

to

```
if(filesize($_FILES['usrfile']['size']) > $max_filesize)
```

and remove the line

```
$ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1);
```

and change this line

```
if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes))
```

to

```
if(!in_array($_FILES['usrfile']['type'],$allowed_filetypes))
```